# Which one is the tx frequency of a repeater?

Tags: repeater

Is that the frequency you transmit on to use the repeater, or the frequency the repeater transmits on?

I've seen it used both ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you program your radio for duplex operation (for use with repeaters), the frequency normally displayed on your radio is your receive frequency, which is the repeater's transmit frequency.

If you transmit, most radios will display the transmit frequency while you are transmitting, which is the repeater's receive frequency.

**The convention in repeater listings (if one frequency is listed) is to show your receive frequency, which is the repeater's transmit frequency**.  Most regions follow a band plan that allows the offset and direction of the other frequency to be guessed, so they may or may not list the second frequency or may explicitly list the offset.